# Compiling MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, makefile, mysql-workbench

I am having problems compiling MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu 13.04. I downloaded the source from the MySQL site and during the configure part where it checks the dependencies it says:

```
checking for python2.6... no
checking for python2.7... yes
checking for Python libraries... not found
configure: error: Python C development headers/libraries not found
```

I than tried to hack and modify the configure file and removed the part where it checked for the Python headers.

By doing that the checks succeeds and I can run `make`, but during `make` process it says it cannot find `Python.h` (which is expected):

`python_context.h:28:21: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`

So I searched the installation directory of `Python 2.7` and found `Python.h`. I searched all over the Internet, but couldn't find an answer how to solve this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: try `apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: Already installed `python-dev` on my machine. Still it cannot find `Python.h`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.10 at least, it's in `/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h`, so you may have to pass an option to `configure` to look in `/usr/include/python2.7`.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot find the `so` file. I'm not sure what the proper solution is, but the following works around it:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
```

But after all of that, I got (unrelated) compile errors, so I gave up, and just went with the slightly outdated packages from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Ubunto 13.04:
Desinstale o mysql-workbench instalado:
$ sudo apt-get -f upgrade

Instale o python-dev:
$ sudo apt-get install python-dev

Instale via terminal o workbench:
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench

Para mim funcionou.

Comment: please post your answer in English